# Using Azure Data Factory transform multiple Excel data to a main file

Tags: excel, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I have two excel files in my Azure Database Container and I would like to transform that data and populate a single database or file in Azure Data Factory.

For Example:

I would like to copy the data from the below excel file:

| Product | Units Sold | Sale Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Carretera | 1618.5 | $ 20.00 |
| Carretera | 1321 | $ 20.00 |
| Montana | 921 | $ 15.00 |
| Montana | 2518 | $ 12.00 |
| Paseo | 292 | $ 20.00 |
| Paseo | 974 | $ 15.00 |

Into the main file with the headers:

| Segment | Country | Product | Discount Band | Units Sold | Manufacturing Price | Sale Price | Gross Sales | Discounts | Sales | COGS | Profit | Date | Month Number | Month Name | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Being new to Azure data factory I could not find much relevant data to my query on the internet, therefore it would be great if I got some suggestions or assistance regarding my query.

**Update**

When performing Mapping in Copy Activity I am not able to see or select the Output columns, the Excel source gets replicated to CSV sink by overwriting the existing data.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't actually pose a problem. Try importing one file, then ask a speicifc question

Comment: Please, share sample input and expected output.

Comment: I have provided the sample input and desired output

Answer (score 0):

You need to map given excel to target file. Use **DataFlow** activity.

**Source Schema.**

[image]

**Sink Schema.**

[image]

I have used CSV file as Sink.

You can map only required columns as shown below.

[image]

When you want to update these records you can use `Upsert if`.

[image]

Comment: I am sorry but DataFlow is not available for Azure Data Factory in my region, is there another way?

Comment: You can perform mapping in Copy Activity as well.